# Python: geospatial analysis

Tags: python, raster, vector

I am starting to learn python.

I have a set of shapefiles (points) and a set of GeoTiff raster files (clipped, and with landcover classes).

Now I want to intersect them. As result I would like to get specific information about each single point. (which land cover class intersects with the point when setting certain buffers e.g: 50 m, 100 m, 150 m)

How to handle such a task using python?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You can use zonal statistics for this, assuming you use the buffers as your zones.